# I am getting 'mapped_list' empty in the following program without clearing it. Please Explain

Tags: python

```
numbers = {}

#assign values to the dictionary 'numbers'

for i in range(5):
 numbers[i**2] = i

#function to check if number is in 'numbers' dictionary
def check(x):
 if x in numbers:
  return True
 else:
  return False

#list with random numbers
rand_nums = [8,9,25,16,18]
filtered_list = filter(check,rand_nums)

#printing 'filtered_list'

# NOTE:- using list() constructor for printing filter object
print(list(filtered_list))


#function to add 1




def add(x):
 return x+1

mapped_list = map(add,filtered_list)

#printing 'mapped_list'

# NOTE:- using list() constructor for printing filter object
print(list(mapped_list))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter function always return iterable object (just like generator). when your code `print(list(filtered_list))` get executed, the value of `filtered_list` gets empty. So later when you mapped same empty filtered list by running this code:
 `mapped_list = map(add,filtered_list)` map function gets empty list.

Chage your code like this:
`filtered_list = list(filter(check,rand_nums))` to get to your rexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you get empty mapped list.

I have tried your code (after a little cleanup)

```
numbers = {}

for i in range(5):
    numbers[i ** 2] = i


def check(x):
    return x in numbers


rand_nums = [8, 9, 25, 16, 18]
filtered_list = list(filter(check, rand_nums))
print('filtered list: {}'.format(filtered_list))


def add(x):
    return x + 1


mapped_list = list(map(add, filtered_list))
print('mapped list: {}'.format((mapped_list)))
```

Output (python 3.6.3)

```
filtered list: [9, 16]
mapped list: [10, 17]
```